# Rolled over husband's 401(k) to IRA after his death. Can I deduct a loss since?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, rollover, losses

When I rolled over my husband's 401(k) into an IRA after his death, the beginning balance was 100,000.00 and now the balance is around 10,000.00

If I sell the IRA, can I deduct the loss on my taxes?

Comment: This isn't your question, but if a financial advisor had any control of that account, you should consider taking legal action.

Comment: You cannot **sell** the IRA as you call it, but you can **take a distribution** from it, and if you like, withdraw all the money from the IRA as a distribution. Assuming that a Roth 401k was not rolled over into a Roth IRA, the entire distribution amount, whatsoever it is, is taxable income to you. If the stocks, bonds, mutual funds, whatever that are in the IRA have to be sold for a loss to pay out the distribution, that loss is not deductible anywhere on your income tax return. Also, if the IRA decreased in value from $100K to $10K **without** any distributions, something is very fishy.

Answer (score 4):

**First:**
In most cases when you inherit stocks the cost basis is stepped up to the date of the death of the person you inherited them from. <strike>So the capital gain/loss is likely reset to zero.</strike> The rules vary a bit for joint accounts, but retirement accounts (401k/ROTH) are considered individual accounts by the IRS. The rules on this have changed a lot in recent history, so it may depend on **when he** died.

**Update:** As JoeTaxpayer pointed out and I confirmed via [this site](http://www.jflconsultinginc.com/news/?p=182) , the gains are NOT stepped up for retirement accounts, so this is a moot point anyway.  Further evidence that retirement accounts can be complicated and seeking professional guidance is a good idea.

> ...[T]here is no step-up in cost basis
>   upon the death of the IRA owner. Most
>   other assets owned by an individual
>   receive a step-up in cost basis upon
>   the death of the person, eliminating
>   all capital gains on those assets up
>   to that point in time.

**Second:** 
Even if you can deduct an investment (capital) loss, you can only deduct it to offset capital gains on another investments. Also you can only do this up to $3k per year, though you can roll over excess capital losses into future years.

**Bottom line:**
I really doubt you are going to be able to claim a deduction. However, due to the complexity of the situation and the amount of money involved. I strongly suggest you talk to a qualified tax adviser and not rely solely on information you gather through this site.

Comment: Basis isn't adjusted on retirement accounts on death of the owner. In a way, it's a double whammy, inheritance tax based on market value on death, but tax due as funds are withdrawn.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I fixed my answer appropriately. I didn't know about the exception to the capital gains step up rule for retirement accounts.

Comment: @JohnFx There is no reason to "really doubt"; be firm in your beliefs. The money that come out as a Distribution from a Traditional IRA is ordinary taxable income to the person receiving it; what happens inside the IRA in terms of capital gains or losses, qualified dividends, etc is irrelevant. The only instance where a loss is recognized is if **all** the IRA accounts are zeroed out and the **sum total** of all distributions from the IRA accounts is less than the basis of the IRA. In such (typically rare) cases, the difference between basis and sum total distribution is a deductible loss.

Answer (score 3):

I trust the 401(k) was a traditional, pre tax account. There was no tax paid, and any withdrawals would be taxable. The account could go to zero, and there's no write off, sorry.
I have to ask - were there any withdrawals along the way? What was it invested in that lost 90% of its value?

Edit - I'm sorry the OP came and went. It would be great to have closure on some of these issues. Here, I'm thinking as Duff said, malpractice, or perhaps a 401(k) that was 100% in company stock. Seems we'll never know.